# Headset microphone and internal microphone switch continuosly generating a noise

Tags: audio

I have an Asus Zenbook ux430un laptop.

My problem is when I plug a headphone with microphone I hear a noise like a heartbeat. I noticed that this happens because, if I don't use the microphone, I think there is some conflict and internal microphone and headset microphone continuously switching to the primary one generating the noise.

This also happens when I press a volume button of the headset. But if I use the mic like in a call or when I open sound options the noise stops and the switching between them too.

Someone can help me?

This happens in Ubuntu 18, 19 and 20, too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a power-save problem. It shuts down or minimizes the power consumption of your sound card when nothing is playing, at least from what I can remember.

The solution is to add
`options snd-hda-inel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N` to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

This is what worked for me, let me know if this isn't the case!

Comment: It works!. Thank you!. Now i found another little problem. If i switch from headset Microphone to internal from sound settings it uses always the headset one. I must unplug headphones to use internal microphone. Can you help me?